# How to send an object with a collection of generic through SignalR on Asp.Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

On my Asp.Net core web app, I'm using SignalR to provide to my angular app some live update. One of the callback is sending data to the client

```
public class DataBatch
{
    public Guid DashboardId { get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<WidgetData> WidgetData { get;set; }
    public DateTime RefreshDate { get;set; }
}
public abstract class WidgetData
{
    public Guid WidgetUsageId { get; set;}
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set;}
}
```

The issue is that `WidgetData` is abstract, and most of its implementations have additionals values. Typically:

```
public class ValueIndicatorData : WidgetData
{
    public IList<ValueIndicatorValue> ValueIndicatorValues { get; } = new List<ValueIndicatorValue>();
}
```

When I send my data to my clients:

```
await _hubContext.Clients.Group(dashboardId).SendDashboardData(notification.DataBatch);
```

My clients only receives the properties declared in `WidgetData`, not the one of my children classes(like the ValueIndicatorData).

How can I provide to SignalR the informations that this object has sub-classes and that their properties should be serialized?

Comment: we had this problem, you can serialize collection to json and send as string.

Answer (score 0):

I ended configuring Asp.Net Core to use NewtonSoft to serialize to JSON, while setting an option to include types, now it automatically serialize the data:

```
    builder.Services.AddSignalR()
        .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol(opts =>
        {
            opts.PayloadSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
        });
```

There is an alternative using the native JSON converter, but it require to build some cumbersome converters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#support-polymorphic-deserialization